# why (int)08 is equal to 0, not 8?

Tags: php

```
echo (int)01; //1

echo (int)02; //2

echo (int)03; //3

echo (int)04; //4

echo (int)05; //5

echo (int)06; //6

echo (int)07; //7

echo (int)08; //0

echo (int)09; //0

echo (int)010; //8

echo (int)011; //9

echo (int)012; //10

echo (int)013; //11
```

(int) was doing right from 01 to 07. But after that it goes wrong. What's the reason of it??

Comment: Read about [numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax).

Answer (score 1):

If a number starts with 0 it is consider an `octal number`

and since these numbers range from 0 to 7 only. You get a 0 since 8%8 = 0

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

**A side note on number systems**

Have you wondered why the next number to 9 is 10? and why in the binary system the sequence is 0, 1, 10, 11... ? And why the octal system allows only values from 0 to 7?

It is because number systems usually increment values based on modulo logic on the base.

For example take the binary number system. Since it is `base 2`, it can only contain values 0, 1 since 0%2 = 0, 1%2 = 1, but 2%2 is again 0

So whenever a greater number comes, say 3. Its value in binary is (increment by one in the preceding place) (put the modulo in the existing place)

So the value of 3 in the binary system is `(0+1) (3%2) = 11`

Though this is not the exact logic, just putting it here for a beginner reference

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 08 is expected to be octal number, like 0x is hexadecimal.

Comment: *"Perhaps"*? Is this an answer or are you guessing?

Comment: In other words, rephrase.